# What does 21q21.1-q21.2 mean?

Tags: genetics, nomenclature, cytogenetics

I am reading a [journal paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1769721216302488?casa_token=S8W54WGsl5kAAAAA:oGIo9-8wDJDUHv2SO4Rl5N8-jgExYHsvWAFqXc7Qv-cTZUHUwvWwFjw6vEkEMzVsQ_thc18S#bib5) about the association between NCAM2 and autism, and I have come across the following:

> We performed microarray analysis and identified a 1.6-Mb deletion of
> 21q21.1-q21.2, containing the NCAM2 gene but no other functional gene.

I am not sure what the '-q21.2' after '21q21.1' in '21q21.1-q21.2' means. Does it mean that the deletion goes between band 21.1 to 21.2 on the long arm of chromosome 21 (21q)? Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Cytogenetic map notation uses the following form:

`A[p/q]BC.D`

Where `A` is the chromosome number, `p` is the petit / short arm, `q` is the queue / long arm, `B` is the band, `C` is the sub-band, and `D` is the sub-sub-band.

So, 21q21.1-q21.2 designates a region on the long arm of chromosome 21, band 2, sub-band 1, between sub-sub-bands 1 and 2.

Source:  [NCBI Genetics Review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Class/MLACourse/Original8Hour/Genetics/chrombanding.html) ([archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111171450/https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Class/MLACourse/Original8Hour/Genetics/chrombanding.html))